# c++ constexpr concatenate char*

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

**Context:**
In my company we generate a lot of types based on IDL files. Some of the types require special logic so they are handcoded but follow the same pattern as the generated ones. We have a function which all types must implement which is a name function. This will return the type name as a `char*` string and the function is **constexpr**.

**Problem:**
The problem is regarding collections which could contain other collections nested potentially N number of times. I therefore am trying to **concatenate two or more `char*` strings at compile time**.

**Pseudocode of what I want to achieve:**

```
template <typename T>
constexpr char* name()
{
    constexpr char* collectionName = "std::vector";
    constexpr char* containedTypeName = name<T>();
    return concat(collectionName, "<", containedTypeName, ">");
}
```

**Note:**
There are examples out there which does something like this but is done with `char[]` or the use of static variables.

**The question:**
How can I make a `constexpr` function which return a `char*` which consists of two or more concatenated char* strings at compile time? I am bound to C++17.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible in C++17.

Comment: I think you won't be able to do it. You MUST know the size of the char array to return it from constexpr and even then you have to trick it since you cannot simply return char* from that. It is much simpler to create a macro which will expand to the char* what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From constexpr you cannot return char* which is constructed there... You must return some compile time known(also its size) constant thingy.
A possible solution could be something like:

```
#include <cstring>

// Buffer to hold the result
struct NameBuffer
{
    // Hardcoded 128 bytes!!!!! Carefully choose the size!
    char data[128];
};

// Copy src to dest, and return the number of copied characters
// You have to implement it since std::strcpy is not constexpr, no big deal.
constexpr int constexpr_strcpy(char* dest, const char* src);

//note: in c++20 make it consteval not constexpr
template <typename T>
constexpr NameBuffer name()
{
    // We will return this
    NameBuffer buf{};

    constexpr const char* collectionName = "std::vector";
    constexpr const char* containedTypeName = "dummy";

    // Copy them one by one after each other
    int n = constexpr_strcpy(buf.data, collectionName);
    n += constexpr_strcpy(buf.data + n, "<");
    n += constexpr_strcpy(buf.data + n, containedTypeName);
    n += constexpr_strcpy(buf.data + n, ">");
    // Null terminate the buffer, or you can store the size there or whatever you want
    buf.data[n] = '\0';
    return buf;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/noTPjKv1K)

And since the returned char* is only depends on the template parameter in your case, you can create templated variables, and create a char* to them, and it can act like any other char*...

**EDIT:**

I have just realized that your pseudo code will never work!! Inside `name<T>()` you are trying to call `name<T>()`.
You must redesign this!!! But! With some hack you can determine the size at compile time somehow for example like this:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t S>
struct NameBuffer
{
    char data[S];
};

// Copy src to dest, and return the number of copied characters
constexpr int constexpr_strcpy(char* dest, const char* src)
{
    int n = 0;
    while((*(dest++) = *(src++))){ n++; }
    return n;
}

// Returns the len of str without the null term
constexpr int constexpr_strlen(const char* str)
{
    int n = 0;
    while(*str) { str++; n++; }
    return n;
}

// This template parameter does nothing now...
// I left it there so you can see how to create the template variable stuff...
//note: in c++20 make it consteval not constexpr
template <typename T>
constexpr auto createName()
{
    constexpr const char*  collectionName = "std::vector";
    constexpr const char* containedTypeName = "dummy";

    constexpr std::size_t buff_size = constexpr_strlen(collectionName) + 
                                      constexpr_strlen(containedTypeName) +
                                      2; // +1 for <, +1 for >

    /// +1 for the nullterm
    NameBuffer<buff_size + 1> buf{};

    /// I'm lazy to rewrite, but now we already calculated the lengths...
    int n = constexpr_strcpy(buf.data, collectionName);
    n += constexpr_strcpy(buf.data + n, "<");
    n += constexpr_strcpy(buf.data + n, containedTypeName);
    n += constexpr_strcpy(buf.data + n, ">");
    buf.data[n] = '\0';
    return buf;
}

// Create the buffer for T
template<typename T>
static constexpr auto name_buff_ = createName<T>();

// point to the buffer of type T. It can be a function too as you wish
template<typename T>
static constexpr const char* name = name_buff_<T>.data;

int main()
{
    // int is redundant now, but this is how you could use this
    std::cout << name<int> << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fr199bazY)

Comment: You could write a `constexpr_strlen` to help size `NameBuffer` to avoid having to guess at its size.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Yep you are right. I have edited, you think about something like that? This is not the best and nicest solution, but works... So I hope the OP can get the idea...